# Image output different color as in preview - HATCHCOLOR TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf

As shown below, when running my codes via Xetex/Xelatex, the output should be a red rectangle (page 1) and a green circle (page 2) with hatch.

[image]

But when opening the PDF file with different programs such as the standart apple viewer or google chrome or adobe, it shows black color:

[image]

Perhaps my code in the preamble is not defined the way it should and this causes some problem. Can anyone help me?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,german]{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\usepackage{pgf,tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary[patterns]


%------------------------------------------------------------
% defining the new dimensions and parameters
\newlength{\hatchspread}
\newlength{\hatchthickness}
\newlength{\hatchshift}
\newcommand{\hatchcolor}{}
% declaring the keys in tikz
\tikzset{hatchspread/.code={\setlength{\hatchspread}{#1}},
    hatchthickness/.code={\setlength{\hatchthickness}{#1}},
    hatchshift/.code={\setlength{\hatchshift}{#1}},% must be >= 0
    hatchcolor/.code={\renewcommand{\hatchcolor}{#1}}}

%--------links unten
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness,\hatchcolor]{links unten}
{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}}
{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr    \hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}
{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread}{\dimexpr\hatchspread}}
{
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchspread pt}{\hatchspread pt}}
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

%--------rechts unten
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness,\hatchcolor]{rechts unten}
{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}}
{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr    \hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}
{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread}{\dimexpr\hatchspread}}
{
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+0.15pt+0pt}{-0.15pt}}
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round, x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \clip(2.22,0.86) rectangle (6.72,5.34);
    \draw[pattern=rechts unten,hatchspread=10pt,hatchthickness=0.5pt,hatchcolor= red](2.26,0.94) -- (6.7,0.94) -- (6.71,5.29) -- (2.26,5.3) -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round, x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm] 
\draw[pattern=links unten,hatchspread=10pt,hatchthickness=0.5pt,hatchcolor= green] (0,0) circle (30mm); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works for me if you remove `\pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}` and use the already present `pattern color=key`. (PGF/TikZ already deals with the pattern color in an appropriate way.)

Comment: you should not use colors inside a form only pattern. At first it doesn't make sense if you want to change the color later, as pattern are stored in objects in the pdf and so the color would be fix, at second it is not allowed for form only patterns to contain color changes. The reference says *The content stream must not invoke operators that specify colors or other color-related parameters in the graphics state;*

Comment: Thx a lot! So much to learn. The next question which comes in mind is:
when the pattern is stored as an object, such that it should not have a fix color, in when/where/how do we define the color afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PGF/TikZ already has a proper interface for setting a form-only pattern's color: [`pattern color`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#tikz/pattern:color). This is just forwarded to [`\pgfsetfillpattern{<pattern>}{<color>}`](https://tikz.dev/base-patterns#%5Cpgfsetfillpattern), though, which deals with the necessary color settings and mixing and whatnot.

So just remove both `\hatchcolor` and `\pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}` from your pattern declaration. For compatibility, I let `hatchcolor` just forward its argument to `pattern color`.

---

I've also removed some `\dimexpr`s that aren't necessary.

### Code

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, german]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
% defining the new dimensions and parameters
\newlength{\hatchspread}
\newlength{\hatchthickness}
\newlength{\hatchshift}
% declaring the keys in tikz
\tikzset{
  hatchspread/.code=\setlength{\hatchspread}{#1},
  hatchthickness/.code=\setlength{\hatchthickness}{#1},
  hatchshift/.code=\setlength{\hatchshift}{#1},
  hatchcolor/.style={pattern color={#1}}}
%--------links unten
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness]{links unten}
  {\pgfqpoint{-2\hatchthickness}{-2\hatchthickness}}
  {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}
             {\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}
  {\pgfqpoint{\hatchspread}{\hatchspread}}
  {%
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchspread}{\hatchspread}}%
    \pgfusepath{stroke}%
  }
%--------rechts unten
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness]{rechts unten}
  {\pgfqpoint{-2\hatchthickness}{-2\hatchthickness}}
  {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}
             {\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}
  {\pgfqpoint{\hatchspread}{\hatchspread}}
  {%
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\hatchspread}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+0.15pt}{-0.15pt}}%
    \pgfusepath{stroke}%
  }
\begin{document}
\tikzset{line cap=round, line join=round, x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip(2.22,0.86) rectangle (6.72,5.34);
\draw[
  pattern=rechts unten,
  hatchspread=10pt,
  hatchthickness=0.5pt,
  hatchcolor=red]
  (2.26,0.94) -- (6.7,0.94) -- (6.71,5.29) -- (2.26,5.3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\tikz
\draw[
  pattern=links unten,
  hatchspread=10pt,
  hatchthickness=0.5pt,
  hatchcolor=green] (0,0) circle (30mm); 
\end{document}
```